# How to handle left associative grammar in ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, context-free-grammar

I am using antlr to generate parser that produces abstract syntax tree. I got some problem about left associative operators. My grammar is like the following:

```
add_expr returns [ASTNode value]
    :a=mul_expr {$value = a;}
    (
        o = ('+' | '-') b = add_expr
        {
        $value = new AddNode(a, b, $o.text);
        }
    )?
    ;
mul_expr returns [ASTNode value]
    :a=term {$value = a;}
    (
        o = ('*' | '/') b = mul_expr
        {
        $value = new MultiplyNode(a, b, $o.text);
        }
    )?
    ;
```

The constructor of AddNode and MultiplyNode is like:

```
AddNote(ASTNode left, ASTNode right, String operatorr)
```

The problem is, for input a-b-c, it is parsed to something like a-(b-c), rather than (a-b)-c. Antlr does not accept left recursive grammar. How to modify the grammar to make the left associative syntax work in expression like a-b-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse `a-b-c` not as `a-(b-c)` and not as `(a-b)-c` but as `a (-b) (-c)`, that is,

```
additiveExpression 
:   multiplicativeExpression
    (   
        (   '+'
        |   '-'
        )
        multiplicativeExpression
     )*
;
```

The above rule is taken from [Java grammar](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g). Save the text and read with an editor, as browser may ignore line ends in it.